# memory alignment and allocation vs malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I am writing a library function in C that will return blocks of 32 bits. I am using malloc() for this purpose. Will the following always guarantee that 32 bits of memory has been allocated in a contiguous fashion?

```
char *base_ptr = (char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char))?
```

How do I make sure that it is allocated over 4 byte boundary?

Comment: I assume you mean 32bits

Comment: If this code is performance critical at all I'd say for allocations this small I would consider some kind of block allocator to avoid both the performance and memory overhead in malloc.

Comment: `malloc` guarantees alignment at least suitable for the largest builtin type. For all mainstream compilers on all mainstream platforms, this means 8 bytes. Since you only need alignment to 4 bytes, no worries.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You will get a contiguous block of *4 bytes* of memory.

Not 32 bytes. If you meant 32 bits then this is not guaranteed, but on a typical desktop machine `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and then, yes, your 4 bytes equate to 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will be contiguous - BUT it won't necessary be allocated on a 4byte boundary.

Comment: In practice it almost certainly will be 4-byte aligned - the standard requires that the return value from malloc is suitably aligned so that its storage can be used for any of the normal C object types without modification.  Unless the OP has an 8- or 16-bit machine, it will definitely be 4-byte aligned or more.

Comment: @Carl: m68k machines could have arbitrary objects allocated on any byte boundary, but were faster if 16 bit objects were word aligned and 32 bit objects were long word aligned. So a `malloc` that didn't care about alignment would be compliant but sub optimal. So this is an important distinction.

Comment: @dmckee, that make sense.  The same would be true for Intel, but I've never seen an implementation that made such a decision.

Comment: @Carl: Well, neither have I. It's just too easy to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

that's 4 bytes. if you want 32 bytes to be contiguous then you should change the 4 to 32.

there is no guarantee that one malloc call allocates contiguously after the next and in fact implementations pad blocks.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(char)` is always `1`.  There is no reason to write that in your code at all.  Casting the return value of `malloc()` also considered bad style by many.

If you need to get as close to 32 bits as possible (minimum overhead) and you want to be *extremely* portable about it, you probably want something like:

```
char *base_ptr = malloc((32 + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT);
```

Comment: Note that CHAR_BIT must be at least 8, so 4 bytes certainly gives you 32 bits. And possibly some more bits. But then there's no guarantee that `CHAR_BIT` is a factor of 32, so if you're seriously supporting all possible sizes then you'll have to deal with having bits left over either way.

Comment: @Steve, I added the rounding to take care of weird `CHAR_BIT` sizes.  I would agree with you that the easiest solution to the OP's problem is probably just `malloc(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the word "alignment" in the title.

Standard `malloc` makes no guarantees about the alignment of the allocation returned. Particular implementations may or may not do helpful things in the that realm, and may or may not have some kind of extension to allow you to control the alignment of the blocks returned. However, these things will not be portable.

As others have said each allocation is guaranteed to be continuous and at least as big as you requested; but there are no guarantees about the relative positioning of any pair of allocations. Nor is there a portable way to discover how large the actual allocation is, which makes it unsafe and undefined to access memory beyond the requested size (again, some implementations may provide extension that address these issues).